# Automatically generate data documentation in the Redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, documentation

I am trying to automatically generate a data documentation in the Redshift cluster for all the maintained data products, but I am having trouble to do so.

Is there a way to fetch/store metadata about tables/columns in redshift directly?

Is there also some automatic way to determine what are the unique keys in a Redshift table?

For example an ideal solution would be to have:

- Table location (cluster, schema, etc.)
- Table description (what is the table for)
- Each column's description (what is each column for, data type, is it a key column, if so what type, etc.)
- Column's distribution (min, max, median, mode, etc.)
- Columns which together form a unique entry in the table

I fully understand that getting the descriptions automatically is pretty much impossible, but I couldn't find a way to store the descriptions in redshift directly, instead I'd have to use 3rd party solutions or generally a documentation outside of the SQL scripts, which I'm not a big fan of, due to the way the data products are built right now. Thus having a way to store each table's/column's description in redshift would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Redshift has the ability to store a `COMMENT` on:

- TABLE
- COLUMN
- CONSTRAINT
- DATABASE
- VIEW

You can use these comments to store descriptions. It might need a bit of table joining to access.

See: [COMMENT - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COMMENT.html)